# Gradle 7 - how to download/copy dependencies jars to folder?

Tags: gradle

Went through multiple threads here, suggested solutions didn't work (most of them for older Gradle)

For example, I have in build.gradle following dependencies

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.15.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.0.9.RELEASE'
```

need to download/copy its jars to some folder.

I do know how to setup a copy task for copying files.
I don't know how to download dependencies.

Comment: What did you already try and didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

well in the end it do work like this

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
     from(sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath)
     into('build/jarsfolder/')
}
```

Comment: To copy only JARs rather than everything on the classpath, you can filter: `from(sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath) { include '*.jar' }`